# How to avoid "a lot of {%include%} gives a lot of <footer>"?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, include

When I need to use a lot of {%include%} (content) in html templates - do unnecessary  extensions appear for each content inclusion? Effects are also applied to each subsequent inclusion of content...
When I can add content inclusion to the first html template expander, everything is fine.
But when I use "pagination" I need to send "page=posts" to paginator.html. I can't find a way to send this variable to blog.html from layout.html...
And I think that in the future I will have the same problems, and therefore it should be solved.

layout.html

```
<div class="container body-content">
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        <footer>
            <hr/>
            <p>&copy; {{ year }}. Сайт</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

blog.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
 <!--♕-->
{% block content %}
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2><br>

        {% for post in posts %}
        <hr>
        <div class="">
            <h2> {{post.title}} </h2>
            <p> {{post.posted}} </p>
        </div>
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'blogpost' parametr=post.id %}">{{ post.description }}</a>
        </p>
    {% endfor %}

    {% include "app/pagination.html" with page=posts %}

{% endblock %}
```

pagination.html

```
{% extends "app/blog.html" %} 
 <!--♕-->
{% block content %} 
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if page.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Предыдущая</a>
            {% endif %}
            <span class="current">
                Страница {{ page.number }} из {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>
            {% if page.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Следующая</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `{% extends "app/blog.html" %} ` from the `pagination.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagination should be a file that only renders pagination content, not the template around this.

This thus means that you implement the pagination *without* the `{% extends "app/layout.html" %}`, so:

```
{# pagination.html, no extends or block #}
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Предыдущая</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="current">
            Страница {{ page.number }} из {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}
        </span>
        {% if page.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Следующая</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

This will prevent the `pagination.html` to render headers, footers, and other content. You can then simply import the pagination as a utility template.